# A simple question in probability that somehow got me confused.

Tags: probability

Let $(X_1,...,X_N)$ be a random arrangement of the numbers $1,...,N$. We say that the $n-th$ component is **inferior**, if there is no $i<n$ such that $X_n>X_i$.

a. What is the probability that the $n-th$ component is inferior?

This one is clear, as the answer states: In a set of $n$ components, $X_1,...,X_n$ there is one minimum. $X_n$ is the minimum with probability $1\over n$. (Is that correct? I am not sure I got it well.)

b. For $m<n$, find that probability that the $n-th$ component is inferior, assuming the $m-th$ one isn't.

I have a problem here: the answers say that it stays $1\over n$ because there is no independence(it didn't explain much.). I, however, arrived at $1\over n-1$ for if $X_m$ is not inferior, then it is not the minimum, and the probability that $X_n$ is the minimum is the number of minimums(1) divided by the number of components that could be that minimum. What am I missing here?

Comment: I think you are using $N$ and $n$ somewhat haphazardly; can you clarify where you mean $N$ and where you mean $n$?

Comment: I made one mistake and I edited my question. Thank you for pointing.

Comment: Can I ask if I am to say "pointing out" or just "pointing"? 
It is really important to me.

Comment: "Thank you for pointing that out."

Comment: And thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @Meitar: Sorry, I did not mean to imply that it was wrong all over the place; I genuinely did not know which was intended in a few places, but it now makes good sense.

Comment: I know, it is okay. I didn't mean it so sound as if I were confronting you at all. I pointed out that I made one mistake so that you wouldn't get confused or something. Given the fact that I am not native, it all comes out not as I genuinely intend. Thank you for saying that. This is how I learn not to cause misunderstanding when speaking English. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both of the answers you quote are right.

For the first part, consider the first $n$ numbers. Ignore their concrete values; just note that they're $n$ different numbers than can be ranked from highest to lowest. It doesn't matter which ones they are and how many or which gaps are in between their actual values – what matters is that all $n!$ permutations of them are equally like, so the chance of the least being the last is $1$ in $n$.

In the second case, your argument seems plausible at first sight – the $m$-th can no longer be the minimum, so that should raise the probability of the $n$-th being the minimum. But look at it this way: First I tell you that these particular $n$ numbers landed in the first $n$ slots. As above, that has no bearing on the probability of the $n$-th number being inferior, because that doesn't depend on the concrete values and only on their order. Now I tell you that the $m$-th number isn't the minimum of the first $m$ numbers. By saying that, I've eliminated $1$ out of $m$ of the $m!$ permutations of the first $m$ numbers. But again that has no bearing on whether they're higher or lower than the $n$-th number – it's just a piece of information on their order. So the probability that the $n$-th component is inferior hasn't changed and is still $1/n$ under this condition.

Comment: Thank you for answering. I am still reading it.

Comment: Should I be looking at some permutations out of all permutations? I am a bit confused here.

Comment: @Meitar: Yes, the order of the elements beyond $n$ is irrelevant -- just focus on the permutations of the first $n$ elements.

Comment: I didn't understand that "1 out of $m$ out of $m!$". What $m$ permutations are we talking about? If I may?

Comment: @Meitar: The first $m$ elements can be permuted in $m!$ different ways. The condition that the $m$-th element is not inferior eliminates $1$ out of $m$ of these permutations. But that the $m$-th element is not the least of the first $m$ is irrelevant to whether it's greater than the $n$-th. I could even tell you that the first $m$ elements are all arranged in ascending order (so none of them except the first is inferior), or that they're arranged in descending order (so all of them are inferior), yet it wouldn't tell you anything about their rank relative to the $n$-th element.

Comment: So let me get it straight; in the first question, there are $(n-1)!$ permutations in which $X_n$ is smallest value, and that gives the probability ${(n-1)!\over n!}={1\over n}$, right?
So, does the seconds question generally stress the fact that the $m-th$ component not being inferior, is merely a collection* of scenarios we already take into account in the first question?

Comment: @Meitar: I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that. Such things tend to get cleared up if you think about a small case. Consider $n=3$: We have $6$ permutations of the first $3$ numbers, of which $2$ have the least number last, so the probability that the third is inferior is $2/6=1/3$. Now I tell you that the second isn't inferior. That eliminates half the permutations because it fixes the order of the first two numbers; but of the three remaining ones, still $1$ out of $3$ has the least number last. The order of the first two numbers is independent of their rank relative to the third.